# Como puedo modificar un producto en c#

Tags: c#

estoy aprendiendo C# y haciendo un CRUD por mi cuenta sin base de datos aun, lo estoy haciendo todo por consola.
Este es el codigo que tengo.

Aca la clase del producto.

```
public class ProductListDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public decimal Precio { get; set; }
}
Productos = new List<Producto>();
```

mi idea es pedirle al usuario el id del producto, se compare si ese id existe y despues pedirle nombre y descripcion a modificar, como podria implementar el metodo de modificar tomando esos 3 parametros?
intente guardar los parametros en variables y despues igualar esas variables a la clase de producto (Producto[i].Nombre = nombre), pero por alguna razon no me funciona, ya tengo hecho los demas metodos pero este no me esta funcionando.

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese id de producto a modificar");
                    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int id))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Id incorrecto");
                        break;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nuevo nombre del producto");

                        var nombre  = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la nueva descripcion del producto");

                        var descripcion  = Console.ReadLine();

                        logica.ModificarProducto(id, nombre, descripcion);

public void ModificarProducto(int id, string nombre, string descripcion)
    {
       if (this.Productos.Any(product => product.Id != id))
        {
            throw new Exception("El id no corresponde con el id del producto");
        }
        
        Productos[id].Nombre = nombre;
        Productos[id].Descripcion = descripcion;
         
    }
```

PD : Se que el metodo esta mal, por eso necesito ayuda jaja

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema lo tienes en este if:

```
    if (this.Productos.Any(product => product.Id != id))
            {
                throw new Exception("El id no corresponde con el id del producto");
            }
```

Siempre tendrás algún producto con un id distinto a aquel que estás buscando. Deberías cambiarlo por algo como:

```
 

    if (Productos[id] is null))
                {
                    throw new Exception("El id no corresponde con el id del producto");
                }
```

Comment: Acabo de probar lo que me dijiste y siempre entra a la exception igual

Answer (score 0):

Confundí tus intenciones.

Tu problema lo tienes en este if:

```
    if (this.Productos.Any(product => product.Id != id))
            {
                throw new Exception("El id no corresponde con el id del producto");
            }
```

Siempre tendrás algún producto con un id distinto a aquel que estás buscando. Deberías cambiarlo por algo como:

```
 

 

       if (Productos.Any(product => product.id == id)))
       {
                        Producto oProducto = Productos.get(product => product.id == id);
                        //Aquí modificarías el producto
       }
      else
      {
         throw new Exception("El id no corresponde con el id del producto");
      }
```

Comment: Porque poner 2 respuestas? Y practicamente iguales? Hay un boton editar debajo de cada publicacion. Borra la respuesta que ko sirve con el boton eliminar y edita la otra para que quede bien completa